# Classic structure - self connected DB table, list

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following:

```
ID NAME PAREN_ID
1   a    null
2   b    null
3   c     2
4   d     3
```

I want to list the ID 4 item, and its all parent, so I would like to get:

```
4 d 3
3 c 2
2 b null
```

I tried something:

```
SELECT * FROM categories c1
JOIN categories c2 ON c2.ID = c1.PARENT_ID;
```

but thats not the good result, even if I try to filter to ID 4, it returns nothing.
Its MySQL!

Comment: Yes, it's MySQL, and RDBMS are not quite good in processing tree-like structures - but that's exactly what you have here. I suggest checking [this article](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) for a pretty good explanation of potential problems you might face, and potential ways out of them. Hint: DB redesign is imminent.

Comment: Try using the Closure model instead of the djacency List model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you can do it with MySQL. I think your best bet would be fetching everything recursively.

```
function getCategories( $id ) {
    $ret = array();
    $cat = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM categories' );
    $curid = $id;
    do {
        $ret[] = $cat[ $curid ];
        $curid = $cat[ $curid ][ 'PARENT_ID' ];
    } while ( $curid );
    return $ret;
}
```

**You should alter this so that it uses the PDO.**

Only problem would be the query returning much data.